# How to identify linkonce_odr llvm functions?

Tags: function, llvm

I need to make a method that returns only the name of the functions that are not linkonce_odr. In the example below, I hope to return: `sc_main`

Example:

```
define linkonce_odr void @_ZN7sc_core15sc_signal_in_ifIbED2Ev(%"class.sc_core::sc_signal_in_if.48"* %this, i8** %vtt) unnamed_addr nounwind uwtable inlinehint align 2

define linkonce_odr void @_ZN7sc_core15sc_signal_in_ifIbEC2Ev(%"class.sc_core::sc_signal_in_if.48"* %this, i8** %vtt) unnamed_addr nounwind uwtable align 2 

define i32 @sc_main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) uwtable
```

What is the best way to identify linkonce_odr functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over all the functions, for each check its linkage via [`getLinkage()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalValue.html#a38ea691c2eeaf3facd74d5cfb0c725b0), then return the names of those in which that method returned [`GlobalValue::LinkOnceODRLinkage`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalValue.html#aedfa75f0c85c4aa85b257f066fbea57caf2b592edf18170e7aff4e8f3bae3360c).

Comment: How do I get to getLinkage(). That is, how do I get from Function to GlobalValue?

Comment: @user2084755 a function [is a GlobalValue](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Function_8h_source.html#l00070).